# Asp.net Hyperlink brings complete file path with server

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have the next asp:Hyperlink in my page

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server"
               CssClass="blueII_left"
               Target="_blank"
               NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("RutaCompleta")%>'
               Text='<%#Eval("Archivo")%>'
               >
</asp:HyperLink>
```

The problem is that when "RutaCompleta" gets Evaluated it brings something like:

```
localhost:62997/SomeRoute/\\Complete File Path.
```

Instead of just bringing

```
\\Complete File Path
```

Any Ideas???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do, I have an application that shows an archive list and each item in the list a direct link to the pdf file

this is how I setup my links

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server"
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Invoices/{0}.pdf",Eval("Number")) %>' 
    Text='<%# Eval("Number") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This is what gets rendered:

```
<a id="gvInvoices_ctl00_ctl06_HyperLink2" target="_blank" href="Invoices/8096.pdf">8096</a>
```

If this doesn't help show me what gets rendered and where you get 'RutaCompleta' from

### ADD THIS CODE TO .CS FILE TO USE LINKBUTTON

```
    using System.Diagnostics; //add this as well

    public void openFile(string _uri)  
    {
        Process.Start(@_uri.ToString()); //use the @ to use the string as is.
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        openFile(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
```

you can generate Linkbutton either programatically from back end or from the front end. This example is from the front end since that is what you are using:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
        CommandArgument="\\server\data\file.xls" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Have in mind that since this uses the Process property of the server it is going to use a good amount of its resources, for a simple Local application its going to be fine but if you want to implement this at a larger scale you are going to have to beef up your server.

I tested this solution and it opens files from my local computer and a server

Comment: The thing is that rutaCompleta brings the complete route to the file in netwrok mode per example RutaCompleta = \\Andres-Laptop\Apps\BaseDeConocimientos\1\Archive.pdf, and instead of bringin only that it comes like  localhost:62997/BaseDeConocimientos/DetalleBDC.aspx\\Andres-Laptop\Apps\BaseDeConocimientos\1\Archive.pdf

Comment: but you actually want to open the file from a Network Storage or are you going to eventually upload that file to a folder within your website?

Comment: that is the path to the folder where the file is stored actually, so yeah I would like to open the file

Comment: try this solution [Hyperlink to network share ](http://forums.asp.net/t/1405319.aspx/1)

Comment: thanks but both of them didn't work, I ended up having the same problem

Comment: OK this is what I used in an application that open file on button click, in ASP you would use a LinkButton instead of Hyperlink but they both look the same on the client side... all the magic is done by the server (check original response for code)   add this code to the .CS file, all that is left for you is to generate linkbuttons, link them to the openFile()